# Excluding 0's from calculations

Tags: python-3.x, average

Hi I have been asked to write a program that will keep asking the user for numbers. The average should be given to 2 decimal places and if a 0 is entered it shouldnt be included in the calculation of the average.

so far I have this:

```
data = input()
numbers = []
while True: 
    data = input()
    if data == "":
        break
    numbers.append(float(data))
count = len(numbers)
if count > 0: 
    newsum = sum(numbers)
    average = newsum / float(count)

print("The average is {}".format(average))
```

Dumb question but how do you ensure the 0's arent considered in the calculation?

Comment: convert the number to float and see if it is equal to a 0, just like the if that checks empty string and then use "continue" instead of "break".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correction: you are not appending the first input to the list

Modification: added an if statement to check whether the input is '0'

```
data = input()
numbers = []
numbers.append(float(data))
while True: 
    data = input()
    if data == "":
        break
    if data == '0':
        continue
    numbers.append(float(data))
count = len(numbers)
if count > 0: 
    newsum = sum(numbers)
    average = newsum / float(count)

print("The average is {}".format(average))
```